# JavaScript function that searches array of objects returns undefined instead of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm working on a function that searches an array filled with objects (each one has strings, numbers, etc...).

My function

```
function findPlayer(array, playerToFind){
$.each(array, function(index, el) {
    console.log(el);
    if(el.user_id === playerToFind){
        return el;
    }
}); }
```

I'm calling it like this (when a button is clicked) I've already checked that $(this).text contains the string value I want. That string is somewhere in the arrayWithData and I want the full object.

```
var player = findPlayer(arrayWithData,$(this).text());
    console.log(player);
```

But "undefined" is returned. Why? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `findPlayer` isn't returning. The callback you passed to `$.each` is.

Comment: Because `each` iterates over (a thing, like an array), it's not really meant for finding stuff in that thing, although you could modify your code to do what you want. `findPlayer` doesn't return anything, and that's what you're calling. Seems more like a simple iteration and return would be sufficient, or using a library like underscore/lodash's `find` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I don't understand... I'm doing "return el"; that should return the element right?

Comment: @Thaenor It *does*--but `each` doesn't care what you return. (Not true, you can return `false` to exit the loop.) You're confusing the callback function (where you do the logical comparison) with the `each` function. They're different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `findPlayer` is calling `.each()` and the `return` statement is in the callback you pass to `.each()`, you're only returning from the callback, not the original function.

Remember, you're *passing* the callback to jQuery, and jQuery is invoking it for you on every iteration, which means jQuery internally is receiving the value from your `return` statement.

Since you're abstracting the search operation behind the `findPlayer` anyway, I'd ditch `.each()` and just use a regular loop.

```
function findPlayer(array, playerToFind){
    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++)
        if(array[i].user_id === playerToFind)
            return array[i];
}
```

Will be faster this way too.

---

Note that in ECMAScript 6, you'll be able to use the `.find()` method.

```
function findPlayer(array, playerToFind){
    return array.find(function(el) {
        return el.user_id === playerToFind;
    });
}
```

Both of these solutions have the advantage of both being native and short circuiting the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I finally understood what's wrong. I'm in a function within a function. I liked your solution using array.find and I'm trying it out, unfortunately it's not yielding any results... I don't understand why, I should output to the console and show a completely different thing in a modal... but it's doing neither.

Answer (score 1):

`findPlayer` returns undefined because you don't have it returning any value.

You *could* modify the function to be closer to this:

```
function findPlayer(array, playerToFind) {
  var foundPlayer;

  $.each(array, function(index, el) {
      if (el.user_id === playerToFind) {
        foundPlayer = el;
        return false;
      }
  }); 

  return foundPlayer;
}
```

Personally I probably wouldn't do this, instead I'd either just simply iterate with a `for` loop, or use something like lodash/underscore's `find` method.

Comment: How does this work? If it finds the object it's returning false. There's no errors when I try this but the console.log doesn't print anything (instead of the object I was searching for)

Comment: @Thaenor, jQuery.each lets you break the loop by explicitly returning `false`.

Comment: @Thaenor: Seeing that you've provided no actual data in the question, we can't possibly know what's wrong. If I was to guess, I'd guess that `$(this).text()` is including some whitespace padding from your document, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Actually I think I need to make another question for that... since it's a whole other issue... strange that it was working so far but just broke now...

Comment: I think I might've found the answer for that... it's JQuery event delegation. Thank you very much everyone! I'm so glad everyone chimed and lent a helping hand... I don't even know which to choose... there's so many great answers...